# Minify JS with VS code extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, minify, terser

**I need:** minify JS file with extension from the store, but I can't find an option to **remove whitespace between html tags** in variables

**I use:** JS & CSS Minifier (Minify) - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=olback.es6-css-minify (because I'm lazy to set up a Webpack)

So if input is:

```
html = `<li class="item">
      <div class="text">
        <p>${array[i]}</p>
      </div>
    </li>`;
```

Output is only:

```
s=`<li class="item">\n      <div class="text">\n        <p>${o[r]}</p>\n      </div>\n    </li>`;
```

The extension uses **[Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser)** to minify the code, but I couldn't find any option to remove the whitespace. Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm curious. What benefit does this have if you minify your code when you save the file? Does the plugin inflate the code when you load it again? Minification should really be left to the build process.

Comment: You seem to acknowledge this fact implicitly in your post, but future readers should be aware that an IDE is *not* the correct place to perform minification or similar tasks. It will make your raw source code nearly impossible to work with moving forward, and can make routine maintenance or other simple changes nearly impossible to accomplish without a complete re-write (dependent on the complexity of the code being minified). You should be doing this the right way with a proper `webpack`/etc. configuration to generate a separate output rather than modifying your source files themselves.

Comment: @esqew i'll save file with extension .min.js etc.. so I can still work with to original file and then just upload .min.js file to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't suggest any plugins for you. There may be a limited selection, since this isn't really the proper way to do things, but you seem to realize this.

If you insist on doing this, and can't find a plugin which fits your needs, you can always use CTRL+F with the regular expression `(?:  |\n)`:

[image: Ctrl + F, regular expression mode, with regex (?: |\n)]

If you use tabs instead of spaces, then you should be able to replace them with `\t`.

The catch is that this will obviously replace spaces within your document, but since browsers automatically remove extra spaces, this hopefully shouldn't be an issue.

I would suggest looking into vite. It's a newer and faster alternative to webpack, and I personally find it a lot easier to use and understand.